# Why l got some empty array from url

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am getting data json from url. Everything working fine, but the problem is sometime I dont get all data json array from url even though it exists. My data array json is about 60 to 70, but I got only 15 to 20 element.

[image: here is my app showing t you only some element and the rest is empty]

My code:

```
 async getData() {


  const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
    message: 'Loading'
  });
  await loading.present();


  this.http.get('/airport.json?code=krt', {}, {})
  .then(data => {

    this.test = JSON.parse(data.data);
    const parsed = JSON.parse(data.data);
    this.items = parsed.response.airport.schedule.arrival.data;
    loading.dismiss()




  }), err=>{
    this.test =err
    loading.dismiss()
  }



}
```

html:

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items"  routerDirection="forward" > 
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr >
            <td > 
                <img src="operators/{{item?.airline.code.icao}}_logo0.png"  (error)="handleImgError($event, item)" class="img-logo">
              </td>
            <td text-left>{{item?.identification.number.default}}</td>
            <td text-center>{{item?.airport.region.city}}</td>
            <td text-right>{{item?.time.scheduled.arrival  * 1000 | date:"h:mma"}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
            <td >&nbsp;</td>
            <td ></td>
            <td text-center>{{item?.aircraft.model.code}}</td>
            <td text-right>{{item?.status.generic.status.text}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
      </ion-item>
```

Some times l got null in some of data ! . how can l avoid null  ? any solution please?

Comment: Are you using `HttpClient`?

Comment: no l used http network native .

Comment: Any particular reason for not using `HttpClient`?

Comment: take look please [https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/]

Comment: yes , because if l used HttpClient l will facing problem with cross domain but if l used native http he will working fine